# Suppose $f(x)=g(\frac{1}{x})$ for $x\gt{0}$, and let $L\in{\mathbb{R}}$. Prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=L$ iff $\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=L$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

I know this is a iff statement so I will assume each side and then try to prove the other. But I do not know how to actually prove this. I know if I assume $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=L$ then $\lim_{x\to \infty}g(1/x)=L$ which means $\lim_{x\to \infty}1/x=0$ hence, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)=L$. Is this logic flawed?

Comment: The underlying result here is that $\lim_{x \to \infty} {1 \over x} = 0$ and $\lim_{x \downarrow 0} {1 \over x} = \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We just need to apply the definition of limit, that is for $$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=L \iff\forall \epsilon \quad \exists\bar x>0 \quad \forall x\ge \bar x \quad |f(x)-L|\le \epsilon \implies |g(1/x)-L|\le \epsilon$$

then by $y=\frac1x>0$

$$\forall \epsilon \quad \exists\bar y=\frac1{\bar x}>0 \quad \forall y\quad0<y\le \bar y \quad |g(y)-L|\le \epsilon \iff \lim_{y\to 0^+}g(y)=L$$

and similarly for the other direction.